# What is the most effective way to manage an overheated device?

Tags: hardware, kindle-fire

I've noticed that my Kindle Fire (fittingly, maybe) feels very hot when I am using it sometimes.  Obviously, common sense would dictate that picking the device up off of the surface it's sitting on is an effective way to have air flow over the surface of the rear of the device.

Even with this quick fix, I still worry about the device overheating.  Is there an active technique for cooling the device down so that it won't sustain damage? (I had thought about a laptop sized cooling mat, but this may be overkill)

Obviously, shutting down the system and walking away will help it to cool off, but I'm looking for something that works while the reader is in operation.

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, because it is about hardware being used for gaming. While the Fire *is* an ebook reader, the question is not about ebooks.

Comment: Looks like there is some interest in reopening this question (based on removing the part about playing games on the device). Please way in here: http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/152/do-we-really-want-to-eliminate-questions-about-readers-that-are-also-tablets and we can decide whether or not to reopen it.

Comment: Do you ever have this problem when reading books? Or is the edited version of this now asking about a non-issue?

Comment: @Caleb It still heats up pretty well, but no, not to the same level.  I think knowing how to cool these devices is pertinent, though.

Comment: @jonsca In what sense of the word "pertinent"? For that matter basic literacy is "pertinent" to ebooks too but is that a reason to field English language questions here? I can also read Kindle books on the laptop I purchased from Amazon and it gets hot when I batch edit my RAW pictures. Should we field notebook cooling issue questions too? As it stands this question is now some mix of "cannot reproduce" and "off topic".

Comment: @Caleb It's been closed and reopened at this point.  If you feel so strongly about it, please cast a close vote and weigh in on the Meta posts.  I'm really not sure why this issue is embroiling people so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For laptops there are underlayers that have fans built in to actively support the air flow. You can position your kindle on such a board, or try to construct something like that yourself from old computer fans ( the ones for laptops are probably to big ).

Comment: Yeah, I had the thought about the laptop fans as well, but I agree.

Comment: Typically the fans are also USB Powered... this is difficult since most readers do not have an actual usb port (just the mini) and the fans will probably quickly drain the battery.,

Answer (score 3):

Stop playing game or using the device for a while may be the best solution.

Comment: See my edit above, please.

Comment: Anthon and jonsca:- I'm sorry if my answer was not helpful. But this is what I generally do to get rid of over heating so i suggested that. And overheating generally happens because of gaming. I have read for more than one hour on my mobile device and over heating never happened. And otherwise also it is good to take eyes off the device to give them rest every hour or two.